# i want to remove the parent of the parent of 'this' in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a span `.icon-trash` in a div parent  in another div parent I want when I click it to remove `.item-append` and I have many of the `.item-append`

```
       <div class="item-append">
           <div class="cont1">
               <img src="">
           </div>
           <div class="cont2">
               <span class="qua">
                   <span class="icon-trash"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I tried jQuery but a don't know what should I put in the selector

```
$('.icon-trash').on('click', function () {
  $(selector).remove();
});
```

Comment: jQuery: `$(this).closest('.item-append').remove();` or with JavaScript: `this.closest('.item-append').remove()`.

Comment: Note that it's generally considered a bad idea to retain this kind of state in the DOM. You would typically want the DOM event to trigger some change to some data that is decoupled from the DOM, and the data changes to trigger the appropriate redraw. In this case, the click event would remove some item from a collection which in turn would trigger a redraw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the `.item-append` element when the `.icon-trash` element is clicked, you can use the following code:

```
$('.icon-trash').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.item-append').remove();
});
```

In the code above, this refers to the `.icon-trash` element that was clicked. The `closest()` method is used to find the nearest ancestor element that matches the given selector (in this case, `.item-append`).

Alternatively, you could also use the following code to achieve the same result:

```
$('.icon-trash').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

In this case, the `parent()` method is used twice to move up the DOM tree from the `.icon-trash` element to its parent `.cont2` element, and then to its parent `.item-append` element, which is then removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the class form the `.item-append`, try this

```
$('.icon-trash').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.item-append').removeClass('item-append');
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/